# Source File move to archive folder in unix

Tags: shell, file, unix, scripting

Unix Shell Script
*Usage:* this type of code is used in most accounts where INFA or DataStage is prevalent
*Task*
Create 2 folders Source, Archive
In the source, keep multiple files of multiple sizes.
The task is to archive the file with highest size by compressing it using tar or tgz format. The archived file name should be *nameoffile_ddmmmyyyy_hhmmss.tgz* and move it to the archive folder or directory
*Configuration file: -*
Source file Path
Archive file path
File Size threshold in integer meaning if the file size is equal or greater than this number, archival process should get triggered.
The above 3 should be maintained in a CSV or TXT based configuration file

Consider all exception handling use cases

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: Looks like homework to me.